# Test -d directory true - subdirectory false (POSIX)

Tags: shell, unix, testing, directory, posix

I'm trying to print all directories/subdirectories from a given start directory.

```
for i in $(ls -A -R -p); do 
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            printf "%s/%s \n" "$PWD" "$i"
    fi
done;
```

This script returns all of the directories found in the . directory and all of the files in that directory, but for some reason the test fails for subdirectories. All of the directories end up in $i and the output looks exactly the same.
Let's say I have the following structure:

```
foo/bar/test
```

echo $i prints

```
foo/
bar/
test/
```

While the contents of the folders are listed like this:

```
./foo:
file1
file2
./bar:
file1
file2
```

However the test statement just prints:

```
PWD/TO/THIS/DIRECTORY/foo
```

For some reason it returns true for the first level directories, but false for all of the subdirectories.

(ls is probably not a good way of doing this and I would be glad for a find statement that solves all of my issues, but first I want to know why this script doesn't work the way you'd think.)

Comment: BTW, `for i in $(ls ...)` is inherently buggy. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: There are colons after each directory name, so that would explain why `-d` is false.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` to log each command run (thus, logging `[ -d ./foo: ]`) would have made this more obvious on its own.

Comment: As another aside, the correct way to use `printf` is to keep your data and your format strings separate. That is, `printf '%s/%s\n' "$PWD" "$i"`. That's not as important in bash's printf as in C's (where malicious format strings can cause actual security vulnerabilities), but there are still bugs that can happen otherwise in the presence of unusual or surprising filenames.

Comment: The thing is $i contains both versions of the foldernames, one with colons to list the files in the directory and one without any colons.
The faulty printf statement is just an oversight on my part, I tried both echo and printf, but ofcourse you are right about that

Comment: @PeterFlash, have you run your script with `sh -x yourscript` or `bash -x yourscript` to log it? Once that's done, you'll know the exact `[` command that's failing.

Comment: Mind you, the obvious problem is that `./bar:` followed by `dir1` is referring to `./bar/dir1`, whereas you're running `[ -d dir1 ]`, not `[ -d bar/dir1 ]`.

Comment: I just used -x and it turns out you are right with your assumption. [ -d dir1 ] gets called instead of [ -d bar/dir1 ].

Comment: You might be able to use the fact that `echo */` will list only directories, each followed by a slash, even if there are also files in the current directory.  Tested with Bash, Dash, Korn shells.  That does not deal with the recursive aspects; you would have to deal with that separately.  (You'd not use `echo`; you'd use the `*/` glob in a `for dir in */` command.  One concern would be 'no sub-directories.  Bash has `shopt -s nullglob` and would generate no names; Korn shell would generate `*/`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your output:

```
dir1:
dir1a
```

Now, the following will be true:

```
[ -d dir1/dir1a ]
```

but that's not what your code does; instead, it runs:

```
[ -d dir1a ]
```

---

To avoid this, don't attempt to parse `ls`; if you want to implement recursion in baseline POSIX sh, do it yourself:

```
callForEachEntry() {
  # because calling this without any command provided would try to execute all found files
  # as commands, checking for safe/correct invocation is essential.
  if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: callForEachEntry starting-directory command-name [arg1 arg2...]" >&2
    echo "  ...calls command-name once for each file recursively found" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  # try to declare variables local, swallow/hide error messages if this fails; code is
  # defensively written to avoid breaking if recursing changes either, but may be faulty if
  # the command passed as an argument modifies "dir" or "entry" variables.
  local dir entry 2>/dev/null ||: "not strict POSIX, but available in dash"
  dir=$1; shift
  for entry in "$dir"/*; do
    # skip if the glob matched nothing
    [ -e "$entry" ] || [ -L "$entry" ] || continue
    # invoke user-provided callback for the entry we found
    "$@" "$entry"
    # recurse last for if on a baseline platform where the "local" above failed.
    if [ -d "$entry" ]; then
      callForEachEntry "$entry" "$@"
    fi
  done
}

# call printf '%s\n' for each file we recursively find; replace this with the code you
# actually want to call, wrapped in a function if appropriate.
callForEachEntry "$PWD" printf '%s\n'
```

`find` can also be used safely, but *not* as a drop-in replacement for the way `ls` was used in the original code -- `for dir in $(find . -type d)` is just as buggy. Instead, see the "Complex Actions" and "Actions In Bulk" section of [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions).

Comment: Spot on. How can I fix this issue? Should I use a different method of reading the subdirs/files?

Comment: @PeterFlash, yup -- see edit adding a proposed solution.

Comment: @PeterFlash just use `find`?

Comment: @marbu, ...so, the problem with `find` is that the `-print0` extension is needed to make it safe. Or `-exec`, of course, which is both standard-defined and safe; but the default print action generates a newline-separated output list, so it's unsafe in the presence of uncontrolled filenames, which can contain newline literals.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed, using `-print0` is a good idea when the output is further processed

Comment: This is the perfect solution. It's not 100% what I want, but this is just what I needed to keep going. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue is that the directory names include a `:`, so `-d` is false.

I guess that this command gives you the output you want (although it requires Bash):

```
# enable globstar for ** 
# disabled in non-interactive shell (e.g. a script)
shopt -s globstar 

# print each path ending in a / (all directories)
# ** expands recursively
printf '%s\n' **/*/
```

The standard way would either to do the recursion yourself, or to use `find`:

```
find . -type d
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a POSIX-compliant answer, so bashisms might not be appropriate here.